# Android Binder Example

Tags: android, android-binder

I am looking for simple binder IPC example in C/C++. Recently I started reading about the Android Binder basic (http://bharathi.posterous.com/android-binder) and gone thru the code in Android source also. Most of the binder usage part is in C++. Can some one explain why C++ is used instead of C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out http://github.com/mcr/Android-HelloWorldService (if you use later versions of android you may have to exchange some includes from `#include <utils/something>` to `#include <binder/something>`).

You can also download the android source code and look into frameworks/base/camera/tests/CameraServiceTest/CameraServiceTest.cpp

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Sam. I have gone thru the some of the native services. But the complexity of thous services blocking the basic understanding of the binder concept. I hope, this example will help me understand binder :)

Comment: Are you able to successfully compile this code?

Comment: Thanks Sam, Wonder example for understanding abt android binder. I downlaoded the sample and i build with the android source code placed HelloWorldService under packages/app and i genereted the apk and so files. But SERVICe is not created.... getting following logs : > ERROR/HelloWorld(491): services :::::: [Ljava.lang.String;@4051b358 > ERROR/HelloWorld(491): services LENGTH is 5 ERROR/HelloWorld(491):
> services isMyServiceRunning ::: false ERROR/HelloWorld(491):
> services[0]=null ERROR/HelloWorld(491): services[1]=null > ERROR/HelloWorld(491): services[2]=null ERROR/HelloWorld(491):
> serv

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the native application compile and working on Android 2.3 source code. For this I had to make two changes - 1st is change the path of binder include files from  to  and secondly to include the libbinder in the libhelloworldservice makefile.

Thanks for this simple example illustrating binder use.